# How to remove the html generated from razor var to Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using MVC5 and passing model from Controller to View. In the view I have

```
  var test = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Data));
```

It work great, I have my model in the js variable. The problem is when I'm going to see my HTML code, the whole variable is rendered [image]

Is there any way how I can remove or hide this code?

Thanks

Comment: Remove that line of code from your razor view and that will be gone from generated HTML.

Comment: I need that value to be passed to my js object, any other way how to do that?

Comment: your current code is doing it ? So what you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

To pass a variable from your server to the client you have two options really:

1. Do what you have done (but the value is rendered in markup)
2. Expose a webapi and query the endpoint in javascript to get the data

Option 2 is best practice.

Without more details on what you're trying to achieve I can't give a more detailed answer, but basically you should be looking into webapi to resolve this.

*note: there are other things you could do like websockets and cookies, but it's unlikely that you want that kind of stuff for this*

Comment: I thought to transfer all my calls to AJAX calls that will be invoked after the page is loaded, but I was not sure is there a way to remove the markup. In that case, I'm going with AJAX, thanks